# How to add a variable to matched expression in sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

Suppose I have the following Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
INCREMENT_BY=5
sed 's/20000/&+$INCREMENT_BY/g' old > new
```

I expect all occurrences of `20000` to be replaced by `20005`, but instead they are replaced with `20000+$INCREMENT_BY`. How can I make this work?

Comment: Is using awk an option?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **double quote** for eval variable, like:

```
sed "s/20000/$(( $INCREMENT_BY + 2000))/g" old
```

Comment: Hi, this makes the output "20000+5" instead of "20005". It seems to be interpreting it literally as a string, is there any way to make it evaluate the sum?

Comment: No. Sed can't do math.

Comment: so since already know the **2000**, why can't directly **add**, like: `sed "s/20000/$(( $INCREMENT_BY + 2000))/g" old`